# Android sqlite - adding only new records to table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am collecting the phone's call log into a table.

This works great:

```
public long populate_Calls(String name, String phone, String type, String duration, String date, String contactid) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
             cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
             cv.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
             cv.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
             cv.put(KEY_DURATION, duration);
             cv.put(KEY_DATE, date);
             cv.put(KEY_CONTACTID, contactid);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);        
    }
```

Let's suppose the table consists of 455 records.
Now the user makes some calls, and refreshes the table. I want only the new call data to be added to the table. I have been trying with this code (I don't really understand it though) but every time I refresh the table, more and more records are added. In the emulator it works fine (there I only got 12 outgoing calls).

I guess I need to watch only the phone number and the date since that identifies the call. If a record with that number and at that date already exists, just jump to the next record. If it does not exist, add it to the table. Right?

```
    public void populate_Calls2(String name, String phone, String type, String duration, String date, String contactid) {
 ourDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NAME + "," + KEY_PHONE + "," + KEY_TYPE + "," + KEY_DURATION + "," + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_CONTACTID + ") SELECT * FROM (SELECT '" + name  + "'," + phone + "," + type + "," + duration + "," + date + "," + contactid + ") WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_PHONE + " = '" + phone + "' AND " + KEY_DATE + " = '" + date + "') LIMIT 1;");    

    }
```

I also tried this but I get

> Failure 1 (near "SELECT": syntax error) on 0x11a2f0 when preparing
>   'INSERT INTO CallTable VALUES(name,phone,type,duration,date,contactid)
>   SELECT * FROM CallTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CallTable
>   WHERE phone = '30411552' AND date = '1338569074976') LIMIT 1;'.

and syntax error:

```
ourDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES(" + KEY_NAME + "," + KEY_PHONE + "," + KEY_TYPE + "," + KEY_DURATION + "," + KEY_DATE + "," + KEY_CONTACTID + ") SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_PHONE + " = '" + phone + "' AND " + KEY_DATE + " = '" + date + "') LIMIT 1;");
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What do you mean by _new call data_. You want to update a row or what?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I want to add only new records to the table.

Comment: And what are these _new records_? How do they differ from the records added by populate_Calls method?

Comment: And why are you refreshing the table? I thought that you store information about calls - a new call means a new row.

Comment: Yes, a new call means a new row. But the phone stores only the first 500 or idk how many calls, and I want to have a database that stores all calls. That's why the simple insert into is not enough for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to check the database for duplicates if you set it up to do that for you when you create the table.

Your table creation string might look like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
        + YOUR_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_NAME + " text not null,"
        + KEY_PHONE + " text not null,"
        + KEY_TYPE + " text not null,"
        + KEY_DURATION + " text not null,"
        + KEY_DATE + " text not null,"
        + KEY_CONTACTID + " integer not null,"
        + "UNIQUE(" + KEY_PHONE + "," + KEY_DATE + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE);";
```

That sets it up so that if you have a combination of phone and date that are the same the record will cause a constraint violation and the insert/update of that record will be ignored (You can change the last bit to ON CONFLICT FAIL to make it throw an error you can catch rather than silently skipping the insert/update operation).

This will make it work whether you use insert(), update(), or replace().

Comment: Nice way to do it! Thanks! I have to add though, it slows down the table population process (in my case from 2 secs to 9 secs), and I am using a single transaction for all inserts.

Comment: Yeah, it'll do that when it checks for constraint violations.  :)

Comment: Isn't there a faster way? 9 seconds is eternity

Comment: I have found it. It is hardcoding but it does it. I collect the callog to an array, and the data from the table to another. I compare the 2 arrays and add the difference to the table. It takes around 3,8 sec, which is way better than 9.

Comment: The other day I faced the disadvantange of this UNIQUE record. It does not force close errors, just mark them as warnings. Just a remark.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The query I proposed does not work, so I removed it!

**Updated answer**

You should do what hm. suggests. Create a unique column in you db, which you populate with something like phone+duration+date, and then do

```
"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " values(" + THE_VALUES + ");"
```

When inserting new values, old values will be ignored.

Comment: Insert Command doesn't have Where clause.
Where Clause is applicable to Update, Select and Delete commands

Comment: Yea, thats why I had to change to my answer :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Unfortunately this adds all the 500 records to my table every time I refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a unique field, where you safe a generated code based on the containing date and phone number. Since the field is unique, it will not added if the code already exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try updateOrInsert.  So first you can try to update the data it will usually return the row id if data exists. then you can insert the data if no row id was returned from updating.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Another scenario to why you are seeing data could be because you are not clearing the application data when you are rebuilding the application.  On your device go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> " your application" clear data

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I need to watch only the phone number and the date since that identifies the call. If a record with that number and at that date already exists, just jump to the next record.

To do an 'insert or replace':

1. Make a composite primary key for the table with the fields `KEY_PHONE` and `KEY_DATE`.
2. Use the `replace (..)` method on the `SQLiteDatabase` instead of the `insert (...)` that you are currently using. So your `populate_Calls` return statement should look like:

   `return ourDatabase.replace(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);`