# General weirdness with SQLite / Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have this simple application that I'm currently writing as practice. Its purpose is to allow the user to send a quote and the author of that quote on a server (in this case a Parse.com backend I have registered) and then show those quotes to other users of the app randomly. So by opening the app, you get a random comment that someone has posted.

The way I'm trying to accomplish this is:

1. On start-up, the app connects to the Parse.com backend and downloads all the currently available quotes (I call those Inanity objects because the quotes are supposedly enlightened but should actually be stupid and nonsensical - anyway, doesn't matter). This is the code:

   ```
   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
           SQLi sqlite = new SQLi(MainActivity.this);
           SQLiteDatabase dbz = sqlite.getWritableDatabase();

           @Override
           public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                           //sqlite.dbDelete();    
               if (e == null) {

                   int size = list.size();

                   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                       ParseObject object = list.get(i);

                       String author = object.get("author").toString();
                       String content = object.get("content").toString();

                       Inanity inan = new Inanity(content, author, 1);

                       Log.d("FOR LOOP" + i, inan.toString());
                       sqlite.insertInanity(dbz, inan);

                   }

               }

           }

       });
   ```

Pretty simple. (**dbz** is an SQLiteDatabase acquired by calling **getWritableDatabase()**, by the way). The code below is the code for the SQLiteOpenHelper **insertInanity()** method that I use to put the retrieved data from the server in the local SQLite database:

```
public void insertInanity(SQLiteDatabase db, Inanity inanity) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CONTENT_INANITIES, inanity.getContent());
        values.put(AUTHOR_INANITIES, inanity.getAuthor());
        values.put(UPVOTE_INANITIES, inanity.getUpvotes());

        db.insert(TABLE_INANITIES, null, values);

    }
```

I pass an SQLiteDatabase object to the method simply to avoid having to call getWriteableDatabase() - I had some trouble with recurring calls if I kept doing that.

After writing the server data on the local SQLite database, the user is taken to an Activity that starts showing the quotes and the author of the quotes in a couple of TextViews. This is the code the retrieves a quote/author object from the SQLite database:

```
public Inanity retrieveInanity(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INANITIES, new String[] {
                CONTENT_INANITIES, AUTHOR_INANITIES, UPVOTE_INANITIES },
                ID_INANITIES + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            return new Inanity("a", "b", 1);
        }

        else {

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String contentL = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CONTENT_INANITIES));
            String authorL = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AUTHOR_INANITIES));
            int upvotesL = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(UPVOTE_INANITIES));

            Inanity inanity = new Inanity(contentL, authorL, upvotesL);
            return inanity;
        }

    }
```

Finally, the quote to be displayed is randomly selected from the locally stored results thusly ("a" is an int variable declared earlier by the way)

```
final SQLi sql = new SQLi(this);

        a = sql.getRowCount() + 1;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int e = rand.nextInt(a);

                if (e != 0) {


                    Inanity inanity = sql.retrieveInanity(e);
                    String content = inanity.getContent();
                    String author = inanity.getAuthor();

                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.downloaded);
                    TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
                    TextView authorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author);

                    Picasso.with(ShowActivity.this)
                            .load("http://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/5356113/il_fullxfull.314192275.jpg")
                            .into(imageView);
                    contentView.setAlpha(0.9f);
                    authorView.setAlpha(0.9f);

                    Animation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 1.0f);
                    alpha.setDuration(2000);

                    contentView.setText(content);
                    authorView.setText(author);

                    contentView.startAnimation(alpha);
                    authorView.startAnimation(alpha);
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this,
                            "Cursor trouble in wonderland!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

The **getRowCount()** method of the SQLi class is this:

```
public int getRowCount() {

        int count = 1;

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INANITIES, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            count = cursor.getCount();
        }

        return count;

    }
```

For the most part. this works great. So, what's the problem, I hear you ask? Well, since I want to refresh the quotes every time the application starts up and get fresh ones from the server, the way I'm trying to accomplish that is by deleting the contents of the Inanity table of the database and re-populate them on start-up. So, I have created this method in the SQLi database helper class that's called **dbDelete()** which I call right at the start of the **done()** method of the FindCallback class of the Parse.com library (although I have commented this out from this code, it works swimmingly: it deletes the contents of the database just fine). Unfortunately, when I do that, it appears that the local SQLite database is not repopulated on app startup for some infernal reason, so I keep getting the placeholder "a", "b" and 1 values that are returned when the **retrieveInanity()** method cannot find cursor contents. Here is the **dbDelete()** method, which is quite simple:

```
public void dbDelete() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_INANITIES, null, null);
    }
```

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time and it's driving me crazy. I understand that the question is pretty convoluted, big and that it doesn't contain any catchy NullPointerExceptions/logcat action but any help would be appreciated. I must be missing something obvious related to the SQLite database use but I simply can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a similar app (one that made calls to a remote database and updated the info on local db). You should try using `db.insertOrThrow`. You will need to wrap the method in a Try...Catch statement. It will try to insert rows, and will throw an exception when a row already exists. You can then ignore the errors by leaving the Catch part blank. This will avoid the deletion and rebuild of the table.

`try {
  db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_INANITIES, null, values);
 } catch SQLException s {
  \\do nothing, as we don't care about existing rows
 }`

If you set up the quote server to have unique identifiers for the quote, then the local copy, your SQLite DB, will not insert duplicate entries. For example, your quote DB table on the server would look something like this

`ID | Quote | Author
1 | blah | J. smith`

Where the column `ID` is set as the unique identifier (or unique key). When your app calls the server and queries the remote DB, your local DB has only records that don't exist added to it.

You also want to make sure, I believe, that you update your cursor adapter in onResume().

Comment: Thanks, great convenience method I hadn't heard of before! The deletion and the rebuild always looked like a very roundabout and wasteful way of achieving what I wanted. This is perfect.

Comment: No problem. I hope it works out for you. Btw, you can also add code to the catch clause to update a record in case you wanted to give authors edit capabilities.

Comment: Thanks again! I have also found out that you can set the tablet itself(upon its creation) to not accept duplicate rows. The accepted answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854919/android-sqlite-adding-only-new-records-to-table  ...shows the SQL statement for that to happen.